# Может ли NODEJS получить доступ к файлам компьютера клиента (посетителя сайта)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, файлы

Господа, возникла такая идея, вот на пример на сайте обычный собранный мной AUDIO плеер, музыкальные треки можно выбрать те которые есть на сервере, это понятно.

Вопрос: можно ли реализовать такое, чтобы клиент сайта мог бы слушать не только ту музыку которая на сайте, но выбрать те музыкальные треки которые у него в компьютере? 
Сервер nodejs...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

Comment: @Suvitruf, что ты хотел сказать прислав мне ссылку?

Comment: То, что вы можете играть клиентскую музыку.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я еще новичок, будь другом, объясни поподробней...  я знаю как создать audio объект и как прописать путь, меня больше интересует серверная сторона...  и сторона компа, как будет себя вести в данный антивирус, не будет ли он ругаться или я слишком усугубляю?

Comment: Серверная сторона тут совсем не причём. Так же как и антивирус. Вы либо проигрываете музыку клиента, либо проигрываете то, что ваш сервер отдаёт.

Comment: @Suvitruf, или я чего то не понимаю или ты меня не понял, я хочу что бы клиент мог слушать ту музыку, которая у него в компьюторе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сервер на node.js ничем не отличается от любого другого сервера.
2. Нет, доступ со страницы к файловой системе получить нельзя.
3. Да, нужно чтобы пользователь загрузил свою музыку в файловый input, при этом отправлять файлы на сервер необязательно (если браузер достаточно современный).

Comment: получается, через input  у клиента  будет постоянная связь между компом и сервером?

Comment: @Air это откуда следует?

Comment: или получается, что можно на данный момент, клиент может создать временный файл загрузить туда выбранные треки слушать их или я слишком раскатал губу?

Comment: а что тогда означает, " нужно чтобы пользователь загрузил свою музыку в файловый input, при этом отправлять файлы на сервер необязательно "

Comment: @Air `<input type="file" />`

Comment: Qwertiy, то что ты описал в ответе я понял, меня смутила фраза из твоего ответа " отправлять файлы на сервер необязательно ", я ее не совсем понял, то что я могу из своего компа отправить файлы на сервер и хранить их там и пользоваться ими, я конечно же знаю... объясни смысл цитаты, которую я привел из твоего ответа

Comment: @Air, можно на клиенте прочитать файл и воспроизводить пока он находится в input'е, либо попытаться его (опять же на клиенте) сохранить в local storage или виртуальную файловую систему сайта (тут могут ограничения на размер сказаться, надо проверять).

Comment: @Qwertiy, ок, я  понял о чем ты))) дошло